# OpenMP - expect data race situation but did not actually occur

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I write the following code and I expect that the data race would occur because of several thread may modify `a` at the same time and get a wrong answer.

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;

    #pragma omp paralle for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        a = a + 1;
    }

    printf("a = %d\n", a);    // correct answer = 10000000

    return 0;
}
```

But the output seems correct:

```
$ gcc test.c -std=c99 -fopenmp
$ ./a.out
a = 10000000
```

I have executed it for several times and it always gave me correct answer.
Why there is no data race occur? Is it just a coincide?
(I know that I should use `reduction` but I just wonder why it still work well without `reduction`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `#pragma omp paralle for` when you meant `#pragma omp parallel for` (notice **parallel** instead of paralle). If you fix this then you'll see your data race.

Comment: Oops.... I didn't notice that. I fixed that and actually see the data race, very thanks. BTW, I used the wrong syntax (`paralle`) but the performance is still improve. Why?

Comment: Good question - this is one of those cases where running the code single-threaded is actually **more performant** than running it multi-threaded. Adding `10000000` numbers in a loop is so fast that just the overhead of running multiple threads slows down your code (quite significantly). When you use `paralle` your code is single-threaded and fast - when you use `parallel` your code is multi-threaded and slow.

Comment: okay I see, very thanks for your explanation, it's helpful!